# How to exclude svn metadata while synchronizing with unison?

Tags: linux, svn, filesystems, synchronization, unison

How can I exclude all the svn metadata while synchronizing with unison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
ignore = Path {.svn}
```

to the .prf file in your .unison folder.

Answer (score 5):

In my case (Version 2.40.65) the accepted solution don't work. It only works for the `.svn` folder located directly in the root directory I am synchronizing.

The following line effectively does the ignore:

```
ignore = Name {.svn}
```

The [Unison manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#ignore) for version the Version 2.40.65 I am using confirms that.

Comment: I use `ignore = Name *.svn` and seems to work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

If you're still having trouble, the following worked for me on Windows:

```
ignore = Path {*/.svn}
```

Comment: I don't see the need to reference some other comment (which you're even referring to, I'm not sure). I'll edit